# C++: undefined references to.. графическая библиотека Dislin

Tags: codeblocks, c++

Установил библиотеку Dislin. 
Для контроля работы библиотеки простейший код (среда Code::Blocks):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dislin/discpp.h>

using namespace std;

int main()  
{  
    Dislin g;  
    g.metafl("cons");  
    g.disini();  
    g.messag("This is a test",100,100);  
    g.disfin();  
}
```

---

```
Build log:  
....  
C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Dislin::Dislin()'

C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Dislin::metafl(char const*)'

C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Dislin::disini()'

C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Dislin::messag(char const*, int, int)'

C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Dislin::disfin()'

C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Dislin::~Dislin()'

C:/Users/Grigory/Desktop/C++/c1/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Dislin::~Dislin()'
```

....

Библиотека установлена в директорию с Code::Blocks: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\dislin

Answer (score 1):

Библиотеку нужно ещё добавить, что бы линковщик мог ее найти.

Слева, в списке проектов найдите свой проект, кликните правой по нему, выбирете properties..., в открытом окне найдите вкладку Libraries. Вот там и начинайте - нужно будет добавить Вашу библиотеку.

Comment: Разве когда линковщик не может найти библиотеку он не пишет следующее:
... No such directory or file..

Comment: он ищет не .h файлы, а .a или .lib (я не помню, как они под виндой называются, если используется mingw). А в этом случае он пишет как раз то, что у Вас в выводе.

Comment: Так с этим разобрался, спасибо! Теперь другая проблема.  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Вот, в каких случаях такая проблема возникает? Я только начинаю программировать, нашел статью на вики про это проблему, не дошло до меня чет..